# Efficient way to replace a single element in the list with None

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list which contains unique strings. I want to remove a given string (if found in the list) from this list but do not want to change the indicies of all other elements in the list.

So I figure that I should just replace the given (and found) string with a `None`.

What's the most efficient way to do so? I thought about list comprehension, but could it be a bit overkill for just one element?

Comment: Sounds like you need a new list.

Comment: My hunch is that you don't want a list, you want a set. This means there isn't any order any more, but it seems conceptually appropriate (and is easy as well as fast).

Comment: @delnan, thanks for the suggestion. but i need a list because their indices will be used for other purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a straightforward approach, since lists are mutable. Once you have the index, you can assign a new value:

```
list[list.index('foo')] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Some list basic may help:

```
In [211]: L = list('abcde')

In [212]: L
Out[212]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

In [213]: i = L.index('c')

In [214]: L[i] = None

In [215]: L
Out[215]: ['a', 'b', None, 'd', 'e']
```

`index` gives the index of the first occurrence and than just assign.

Comment: is this quicker than list comprehension?

Comment: The time is spend finding the string. Replacing is fast, no matter how big the list is. The method `index()` comes with lists. It is unlikely that you will get any faster. If you need to search only once, converting the list to a set won't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the element, any method you choose will either be O(n) or O(log(n)) (if available). Once you know the index of the element, replacing an element is a constant time operation.

The real questions are whether you actually want a list or not. If don't need order, then use a set, in which case lookup and insertion are O(n). If you need order, and you want to swap things in an and out, then consider a tree or heap structure.

You're probably missing the information that python lists are array-backed, rather than linked structures.

Comment: By doing `mylist[index] = None`

Comment: @Marcin, I do need order. Good suggestion on using trees, looking into that.

Comment: @MLister *Why* do you need order? If you are swapping in and out, you probably don't need your datastructure to be ordered. You only need order if you need to iterate over the structure in order, or otherwise process it in order. Otherwise, you can likely store ordering data later for future sorting if necessary.